# Create a capsule shaped layout with 2 different background colors

Tags: android

I want to create a view similar to this image.

[image]

Is there a similar tagView or drawable resource file?
The text inside can have any length, so taking its image as background is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners android:radius="18dp" />

<size
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="20dp" />
<solid android:color="#808080" />
```

This one will be your bottom drawable with grey background, and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp" />

<size
    android:width="140dp"
    android:height="20dp" />
<solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

The white one. Next place it one at other in your layout using ConstraintLayout or RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. First you need to create Background for Right and left capsule like this.

Left capsule Background

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            />
        <gradient
            android:angle="45"
            android:centerX="35%"
            android:centerColor="#f2efef"
            android:startColor="#f4efef"
            android:endColor="#faf6f6"
            android:type="linear"
            />
        <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"
            />
        <size
            android:width="270dp"
            android:height="60dp"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#878787"
            />
    </shape>
```

Right capsule Background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    />
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:centerX="35%"
    android:centerColor="#b1b1b1"
    android:startColor="#cec9c9"
    android:endColor="#b9b3b3"
    android:type="linear"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="270dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#878787"
    />
```

Final Your Capsule like this Gives a background to textview like this.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Hibernate"
                android:textColor="@color/imagepicker_black"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:background="@drawable/capsule_background_left"/>
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1 Yr"
                android:textColor="@color/imagepicker_black"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="@drawable/capsule_background_right"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```